# how to keep 0 as first number in excel

Tags: excel, csv

i have a csv file and it contains phone numbers.. sample number is 09131238732 and i wanted to keep the 0 as my first number but my problem now is it gets removed when i re open the csv file.. like when i save it with the 0 as first number and formatted it to text when i re open the csv file it returns to general as formatted and the 0 removed. is there a way to solve this?.. they said that i need to use =TEXT(A1,"00000000000") but i think it will be a hassle for me since the file contains 100's of data with phone number.i also create a custom format cell but when i saved it and re open the csv file the formatted cell goes back to general and the custom cell that i created removed. is there anyone know how to properly create a custom format cell so that whenever i close and re open the csv file the custom format still remains?.

Answer (score 3):

To open the CSV file, don't just use File > Open or double click. Instead, use Data > from Text to open the CSV file. This will open the text import wizard. In Step 3 of the wizard you can select each column in turn and set its data type. Set the data type of columns with leading zeroes to "Text" and the leading zeroes will be retained.

Comment: it is still the same. when i save it and re open the csv file it still removes the 0 as the first number...

Comment: is there a way  to create a custom format cell?.. i tried it but it gets removed also.. what i did was right click on the cell> select format cell> select custom then input 00000000000 and click ok.. and save the csv file but when i re open the file it removes the 0 and the format that i created also remove.. i think my approach is not the right one so i want to know how to create a custom format cell so that whenever i close or open the file the format cell will still remain..

Comment: Excel number formats don't do leading zeros. A number format will not have any effect on the underlying value. Only the value will make it to the CSV file if you save as CSV.  Your only chance is to use the Text data type. A format will not change the underlying value. A number is a number and, when cycled through a CSV, it will always be shown as a number in Excel, i.e. no leading zeroes. Again, your only chance is to use Text as the data type. Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Apparently, Office 2016 Excel requires a slightly different process than that of the Answer: Use "From Text/CSV" (Data ribbon, "Get & Transform Data" group). In the pop-up, Select the file; click Import. In the next pop-up, select the File Origin (e.g., UTF-8) and "Do not detect data types" for "Data Type Detection." (Optionally, click Edit and choose options using the pop-up GUI.) Select "Load To" from the pull-down menu at the bottom of the window, then select a cell in a blank worksheet (e.g. A1). From there, you can format the columns; the formatting is apparently preserved on refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Change the phone number from `09131238732` to `'09131238732`, adding the `'` sign. It will stay as intended.

If the phone numbers are easy to be selected, select them (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to select different ranges) and run the following:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim rngCell     As Range        
    For Each rngCell In Selection
        rngCell = "'" & rngCell
    Next rngCell    
End Sub
```